# how to use mouseover event in a img icon of a file in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, angular6

```
<td>
 <img src="Icon_download.svg" (click)='downl(item.csv")' (mouseover)="xx">
 <img src="icon_download_red.svg" (click)='downl(item2.csv")' (mouseover)="yy">
</td>
```

It is not displaying the content on mouseover. Can somebody say what Im doing wrong?

Comment: When you are saying "It is not displaying the content on mouseover.". What content are you expecting to be displayed?

Comment: @Afsa I need to display the value which is in xx.

Comment: That's not what mouseover does. It is used to bind a function to the mouseover event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(mouseover)` is an event handler, it expects a function to be executed and passes a mouse event.
If you want to show a tooltip with a text value, use the HTML [Title Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp)

`<img src="Icon_download.svg" (click)='downl(item.csv")' title="xx">`

You can show text dynamically by using Angulars [template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax):

`<img src="Icon_download.svg" (click)='downl(item.csv")' [title]="xx()">`

Comment: no problem @sasi, it would be really cool if you could mark the answer as solved :)